# is it possible to print more then one property from the json body in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

been trying to print more then one property in the json body in flutter on the same line. Can't seem to figure out how to. any help would be much appericated.

```
void getData() async {

Response response = await get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);
print(data);
print(data['id']);
```

}

this is what i get back in the terminal when i run it.

```
[{"id":475,"result":{"value":"android","type":"_extensionType","method":"ext.flutter.platformOverride"}}]
```

[ +373 ms] I/flutter ( 4562): {userId: 1, id: 1, title: delectus aut autem, completed: false}
[        ] I/flutter ( 4562): 1

Answer (score 1):

If u want to print some data in same line try this :

`print('response: ${data} id :${data['id']}')`

Tip: generate models that will rearrange all the data for u. link - [json to dart](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/)

Answer (score 0):

Root is array.

try this
`data[0]['id']`